# How to Display content from other website (on the same domain)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress on my site http://thedripple.com.
I want to show just table from posts of http://thedripple.com/products (Another wordpress installed) on my main site's posts!
How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since they are on the same domain perhaps:

```
<div id="posts"></div>

$('#posts').load('/products/hp-envy-spectre-xt #wp-table-reloaded-id-2-no-1');
```

You'll want to pull in the css somehow so that it displays correctly.  [example:](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg6wF/)

Comment: Can't i do something with javascript ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828109/show-div-from-another-website ), I just want to display the table not the whole post!

Comment: sure that would work.  Is your Id going to be static?

Comment: I'm not good at javascript :\, about id, yes it'll be static!

Comment: what posts exactly are you trying to get

Comment: Suppose there's article about HP Envy Spectre XT on my main site, so I would like to display whole spec table of the laptop from http://thedripple.com/products/hp-envy-spectre-xt/ and something similar to all posts!!!