# Embedding a div from another website on my own (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to embed a div from another website on my own without using anything other than HTML and/or CSS? I have not really started on JS, jQuery or PHP yet so I would like to see if there is a way without it.

The div I would like to embed is:
**http://imgur.com/user/BeachyBoy/favorites/#likes**

Comment: `<iframe>`, but this'll embed the ENTIRE page. if you want just a chunk of it, then you'll need to write some code.

Comment: Simple answer - No. HTML and CSS are just display for your web app, just like console is output for basic C commands, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iframe to implement. 
For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="4000" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

If you need to import a chunk of the page, it is not possible only using HTML/CSS. it involves cross-domain issue, so jquery, ajax..are needed.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you by any chance know how to do it using jQuery?

Comment: Check this link, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828109/show-div-from-another-website

Answer (score 5):

You can use an iframe to insert content on your site from another domain. Not sure you can isolate just a single div though. The code to embed external content is:

```
<iframe src="http://addressofsite.com"></iframe>
```

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for info on how to use the tag and all its available options.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way.

I wanted to embed below subscription from [this website](https://faithoverflow.com)

[image]

I collected `ID` for the div which is `mlb2-7717504`

Then use iframe code as below.

```
<iframe src="https://faithoverflow.com#mlb2-7717504" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

The output is [here](https://codepen.io/chaitanyajoy/pen/XWGaLGB)

[image]