# Loading Named Element from Another Webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I've been struggling to find a solution to this for a few days now. There's even another Stackoverflow page which sounds like almost exactly what I need, but I cannot get the solution there to work: [Show div from another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828109/show-div-from-another-website)

The short version is that I have a page (/reference.html) that has many named Div elements (div id="Red", div id="Blue", etc). I would like to be able to call them in other pages on my website (/content1.html, /content2.html), potentially more than one on a page.

It could be user error of some kind, but every solution I've attempted, including the jQuery option in the linked question, has resulted in blanks.

Thank you for any help in pointing out common mistakes to check for, or alternate solutions.

Edit: Adding more details. I've tried several other things that just felt foolish in comparison, so I won't include the 'obviously wrong' category. What I've tried that seems like it should work (but hasn't yet) is below:

References.html

```
<div id="Red">Red content.</div>
<div id="Blue">Blue content.</div>
<div id="Green">Green content.</div>
```

Content1.html

```
$('#insertHere').load('/References.html #Red');

<div id="insertHere"></div>
```

Content2.html

```
$('#insertA').load('/References.html #Blue');
$('#insertB').load('/References.html #Green');

<div id="insertA"></div>
<div id="insertB"></div>
```

Edit again: The references page has some formatted cards in each div. I'd like to be able to pull an individual card from the page, without having to make a page for each card or constantly copy-paste the entire code for the card.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: A few obvious questions: Have you loaded jQuery? Where is /references in your file system compared to /content1?  And what errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: Well, now I feel foolish. I had jQuery loaded before, but I made some updates to the header and must have accidentally removed it. Thank you :) (and sorry for wasting your time)

Comment: :)  We've all been there.