# How to display an HTML Element from an external site

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I know a class id, is it possible to read the HTML data and write as a string the HTML that contacts that class id?

Doesn't have to be concrete code for this, any resources are appreciated that may make this possible. I'm unsure if there are any javascript functions that allow this.

Comment: JavaScript can not just read any 3rd party site. Needs to have CORs enabled for your domain.

Comment: do u have any idea about ajax function ? u can use this this will be very helpful

Comment: Have you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828109/show-div-from-another-website

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing this from another site and assuming you have CORS setup to allow the request, you can use jQuery's `get()` to fetch the item:

```
 $.get('https://example.com/path/to/page.html')
  .then(function(data){
      var elem = $(data).find('yourSelector');
      /* 
          Do something with the element 
      */
  });
```

This also assuming that the element is always on the page and the page always resolves.

Comment: And if you don't have the CORS setup, can a view source chart be created as a string and then filtered if know start and end tag. Such as chrome you can do view-source: to see the HTML code, is there an option to do that via that method

Comment: @Lev No. Since you are fetching content from a third party site and making a network request to do it, the browser is going to require that CORS is set up to allow it. This is a security feature to prevent malicious scripts fetching your username/passwords/cookies and sending them off to another site. This is something you set up to say it's ok for the browser to request stuff from the other site.